# The Swift_Transport_MailTransport class is deprecated since version 5.4.5 and will be removed in 6.0. Use the Sendmail or SMTP transport instead

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I'm using the SwiftMailer class to send mail using the php mail() function or SMTP depending on my app's configuration (development or production). My code looks like this :

```
// Default mailer: php mail() function
$this->transport = \Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

// If a SMTP host is defined
if (isset($_SITE['site_smtp_host'])) {
    $this->transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance($_SITE["site_smtp_host"], 587)
                    ->setUsername($_SITE["site_smtp_user"])
                    ->setPassword($_SITE["site_smtp_pass"]);
    }
```

Since SwiftMailer 5.4.5 I'm getting this deprecation notice :

> Exception: UNKNOWN ERROR (16384): The Swift_Transport_MailTransport
>   class is deprecated since version 5.4.5 and will be removed in 6.0.
>   Use the Sendmail or SMTP transport instead.

Should I use `Swift_SendmailTransport` as I was using `Swift_MailTransport` ? Will it work it the same environnements ? Does it also use the php mail() functions ? If not, is it not possible to use the php mail() function with SwiftMailer anymore ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, about deprecation from swift mailer site:

> It is advised that users do not use this transport if at all possible
>   since a number of plugin features cannot be used in conjunction with
>   this transport due to the internal interface in PHP itself.
>
> The level of error reporting with this transport is incredibly weak,
>   again due to limitations of PHP's internal mail() function. You'll get
>   an all-or-nothing result from sending.

If you need 100% compatible solution, you need to check `php.ini` settings and OS platform http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

For unix platform will be enough to call `->setCommand` with `ini_get("sendmail_path")` value. For windows platform support need to check `smtp` option.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it’s done. Note that the Sendmail path is not the same on all servers.

```
// Get the Sendmail path
$sendmailPath = ini_get('sendmail_path');
$sendmailPath = ($sendmailPath === false || $sendmailPath === '') ? '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs' : $sendmailPath;

// Create the transport method
$transport = new \Swift_SendmailTransport($sendmailPath);
$mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport); // 5.6 or...
$mailer = new \Swift_Mailer($transport); // ...6.2

// Now compose and send your email
```